# SQL is sorting to update an Index that should already be sorted properly

Tags: sql-server, sorting, indexing, spool

I have a simple update query in SQL Server, let's say:

```
UPDATE TableName
SET Field1 = '1'
WHERE Field1 = '2'
```

I can tell from the Actual Execution Plan that updating the table itself takes almost no time at all (because there is an index on the table sorted first by Field1). The problem is updating the indexes, particularly the sorting that takes place before index can be updated. For two of the indices, I understand why the sorting is necessary: they are currently NOT sorted first by Field1. However, one of them is ALREADY sorted first by Field1, so I would think the sorting step that precedes updating the index would be unnecessary. It does sort it before updating that index though, and it takes up 23% of the execution cost.

This wouldn't be a problem except that the data in the table has 25+ million rows and the sorting takes so long that the application keeps timing out waiting for it. In my mind, that 23% sorting step on the one index that should be unnecessary. Any theories on what might be causing it to sort again would be appreciated.

[image: Image of Execution Plan]

Comment: Is this a clustered or non clustered index? Unique or not?

Comment: Non-Unique, Non-Clustered

Comment: Post the image to Instagram/Twitter/whatever and include the link here. I'll add it for you. Also, can you include the definition of the two troublesome indices?

Comment: I added a link to an image if the execution plan. I can only describe the issue generically because of confidentiality issues, but the index I am concerned with is using Field1 as its key, so it should already be sorted in a way that makes finding and updating that field easy. Shouldn't need to sort again.